# How does XGBoost use MAE as objective function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, xgboost, boosting

XGBoost did not allow to use absolute error as objective function in the past since it is a non-differentiable function and its Hessian is equal to 0. However, it does allow to use it now (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html).

How does it do it and how can I define non-differentiable custom objective functions?

I've tried to implement it as simply:

```
def absolute_error(predt, dtrain):
    y_true = dtrain.get_label()
    errors = y_true - predt
    grad = -1.0 * np.sign(errors)  # Gradient (negative of the sign of the error)
    hess = np.zeros_like(y_true)  # Hessian (constant, 0, in this case)
    return grad, hess
```

But it obviously does not work

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006341/xgboost-how-to-use-mae-as-objective-function) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351874/how-to-interpret-smooth-l1-loss), the absolute error or L1 loss function is not continuously twice differentiable. XGBoost uses the second derivative is used as a denominator in the leaf weight, hence a constant 0 as the Hessian does not work.

We can use a smooth version of the L1 loss instead (as shown below) or some other smooth Loss functions as Huber-loss, which gets rid of the discontinuity at 0 and in the nbd.

[image]

```
def absolute_error_obj(alpha):
    def absolute_error(labels, predt):
        x = predt - labels
        grad = np.sign(x) 
        grad[np.abs(x) < alpha] = 2/alpha*x[np.abs(x) < alpha]
        hess = np.zeros_like(labels) 
        hess[np.abs(x) < alpha] = 2/alpha
        return grad, hess
    return absolute_error
```

This works, as demonstrated with the `diabetes` dataset, since the loss function decreases over time and converges.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(tree_method="hist", objective=absolute_error_obj(75))
reg.fit(X, y, eval_set=[(X, y)])
```

[image]

The next figure shows the scatter plot of the actual values and the predicted values for the target variable `y`.

```
ypred = reg.predict(X)
plt.scatter(y, ypred)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!Thank you!

Comment: @Sandipan Dey
 how do you come up with a value of 75 for alpha?